# Some Cloud Functions regions were unreachable, please try again later

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy my firebase project as usual, but today I am facing an error that I couldn't find a refrence for online.

```
i  deploying database, functions, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
✔  database: rules syntax for database my-project is valid
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (28.29 KB) for uploading

Error: Some Cloud Functions regions were unreachable, please try again later.
```

My functions are errors-free, I didn't change anything since they where working last time. I appreciate your kind help on that.

Comment: Now I am getting: `Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.`, it looks like a Google side error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It seems there were issues deploying to some regions earlier today. The problem should now be solved, so please try again and let me know if it's still failing.

Comment: Hey Frank, nice to meet you again. Yes, i can deploy now without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue deploying from the Netherlands. Circumvented it by deploying through a VPN in New York.

Comment: this answer could be a comment as you are not explaining what is happening and only providing a suggestion (workaround).