# Firebase deploy error - some cloud functions regions were unreachable please try again later

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, circleci, firebase-tools

i'm trying to deploy my firebase functions using circleCi

`firebase deploy --only functions`

but i`m receiving this error in firebase-debug log.

`some cloud functions regions were unreachable please try again later`

checked:

https://status.firebase.google.com/

https://status.cloud.google.com/

everything fine...

anyone with this issue too?

ps: using firebase-tools v9.9.0

ps2: all my project is located in us-central1.

Comment: If they have been deployed before without problems, this has happened before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689102/some-cloud-functions-regions-were-unreachable-please-try-again-later). If it's the first time your deploying, please share some code of the ones giving you this error.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, i've deployed multiple times this week with no problem, its the same issue from the link you posted, maybe i need wait more time before trying again as Frank said in that post that was a temp issue.

Comment: I deployed today to europe-west, went well, got a message to update the sdk afterwards, updated and deployed more without hickups, It should be resolved soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you you need to update your firebase-functions SDK.

Comment: everything is updated, yesterday i deployed with no problem, but not today.